# Check if li exists within ul

Tags: jquery

I have one ul called : id =  `listProjectRelated`

On the if condition in document ready, I need to add the li element whose id will be: `liProfessionalMemberships`

I want to add the li item if it does not exist in the ul element. How can I do that?

```
 if ($('#hdnValueProMembershipSoid').val() != "0") {
     btnAddMore.show();
     $('#listProjectRelated').empty();
     $('#listProjectRelated').append("<li id='liProfessionalMemberships'>Professional Membership</li>");
 }
```

I have almost 6 different li elements that I need to add.

Comment: Can you elaborate please. If all li elements have different identifiers, then use one of the solutions below and replicate per element. If only some have identifiers and others don't please elobarate what to check for to see if they exist. What makes them unique if not an identifer?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl +1, the comment left under my answer suggests this is not the whole question.

Answer (score 4):

`$('#listProjectRelated li').length` should do the trick.

Comment: #listProjectRelated always exists

Comment: -1: not sure about the up-votes seeing you are using the wrong identifer: `$('#listProjectRelated')` is not what is being added but the container which already exists.

Comment: hmmm yes my bad, i think what he meant was this
$('#listProjectRelated li').length

Comment: I think what he/she meant was liProfessionalMemberships, however the question lacks clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You do mean if the element by the id "liProfessionalMemberships" doesn't exist then add it don't you?

```
if (!$('#liProfessionalMemberships').length) {
    // ok to add stuff
}
```

Comment: but i also have different id to add , not only one li id

Answer (score 1):

Check if `$("#liProfessionalMemberships").length` is 0. If it is add the li to the page.

If you have  several list items you can put them in a list with their respective ids and titles (the visible text):

```
var lis = [
     {id: "liProfessionalMemberships", title: "Professional Membership"},
     {id: "...", title: "..."}
];

for (var i=0;i<lis.length;i++)
{
    var li = lis[i];
    if ($("#" + li.id).length === 0)
    {
        $('#listProjectRelated').append("<li id='" + li.id + "'>" + li.title + "</li>");
    }
}
```

Comment: ok fair enough. it always makes me wonder why. same with count()

Comment: given the extra info about the other list elements, this is the most sensible method. Just one error `+ lis.id +`

Answer (score 0):

You need the `length` property of the object:

```
if($('#hdnValueProMembershipSoid').val() != "0") 
{
    btnAddMore.show();
    $('#listProjectRelated').empty();

    if($('#liProfessionalMemberships').length == 0)
    {
        $('#listProjectRelated').append("<li id='liProfessionalMemberships'>Professional Membership</li>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($('#liProfessionalMemberships').length == 0)
    {
        $('#listProjectRelated').append("<li id='liProfessionalMemberships'>Professional Membership</li>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like the following:

```
if($("#listProjectRelated #liProfessionalMemberships").length) {
       $("#listProjectRelated ul").append('<li id="liProfessionalMemberships">Professional Membership</li>');
}
```

Comment: welcome new person. given that there were 5 answers already, does this really contribute?

Comment: I just post my answer what i known correct for the question. I knew very  well that you are genius more than me.. But still I need to learn these things as well. Thanks and am not here for the upvotes.. :-)

Comment: I may not know any more that you do. Except one thing: if some answers exist and you can see that they are right, best option is to move on or +1 those which answer the question best.

Comment: ohh okie.. but still he didn't accept as an answer... he needs some more thing to do.. I don't have comment option. So post the answer and try to provide wat he needs exactly. By the way... do u need an upvote??